# accessing fields from non-root project in gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

this seems like it should be very simple, but I'm stuck! I have a gradle task that zips some files and creates an archive. I want to suffix the name of the archive with the version string from the project I'm in (this is a subproject in a multi-project build)

there's another task in this same build.gradle file that accesses this version field, that I want to access too. it looks like this:

```
task releasePublishAuto(dependsOn: [tasks.cppApiVersion, rootProject.tasks.releasePublish]) {
    doLast {
        println("############################################################")
        println("# PUBLISHED CPP API WITH VERSION: $version")
        println("############################################################")
    }
}
```

you can see it accessing the version variable and printing it using $version. it prints something like `# PUBLISHED CPP API WITH VERSION: 1.256.4-SNAPSHOT`

now, my task is a zipping task, so it's a bit different:

```
task zipGeneratedCppClientApi(type: Zip, group: "code generator", dependsOn: [tasks.cppApiVersion, "generateCormorantCPP"]) {
    from(fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/generated/cormorant_cpp", include: "**/*"))
    archiveFileName = "$buildDir/distributions/generated-cpp-api-$version"
}
```

I would expect this to create a zipfile named `generated-cpp-api-1.256.4-SNAPSHOT` but instead i get one named `generated-cpp-api-null`. As far as I can tell this is because in the context of my zipping task, `version` refers to the version of the zipping library (or somesuch), not the version of the current project. I've tried instead accessing `rootproject.version` but that's also null - this isn't the root project but a subproject thereof!

How can I access the version field in this non-root project in gradle?

to clarify: if I remove `type:zip` from my task, `version` points to the correct value, but without `type:zip` it doesnt create a zipfile and so isnt very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a Zip task, the `version` property refers to the [AbstractArchiveTask.version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask:version) property, as you have somehow guessed, and not to the current project version property. As you can see, this `version` property has been deprecated on AbstractArchiveTask class, maybe to avoid such confusion.

To use project version instead, simply use `${project.version}` as in following example.

in your subproject build script:

```
version="1.0.0"
tasks.register('packageDistribution', Zip) {
    println("version from AbstractArchiveTask : $version") // => here, version will be null
    println("version from project: ${project.version}")   //  => here, version will be "1.0.0" as expected
    archiveFileName = "my-distribution-${project.version}.zip"  // => my-distribution-1.0.0.zip  as expected
    destinationDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir('dist')

    from layout.projectDirectory.dir("src/dist")
}
```